# convert javascript variable value into PHP value

Tags: javascript, php

Javascript:

```
function setitem(id, phpvalue){
                var data = {
                    Sub_category: $("#Subcategory").val()
                }
                var formsubmission = '<?php echo base_url().'index.php/AJAX/get_item'?>';
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: formsubmission,
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response){
                      $("#Item_"+id).find('option').not(':first').remove();
                      $("#Item_"+id+" option:first").after(response);
                      $("#Item_"+id).prop("disabled", false);
                      var item_value = '<?php echo $Items["+phpvalue+"]["Item"]?>';
                      $("#Item_"+id).val('<?php echo $Items[0]["Item"]?>');
                      $("#Item_"+id).selectpicker('refresh');
                    }
                })
            }
```

Anyone can please tell me How can I use phpvalue as an array index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing javascript value to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086813/passing-javascript-value-to-php)

Comment: in simple words you cannot do it that way - when the javascript is to be executed (and phpvalue exist), the php would have already run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Can be achieved by converting php array to json then javascript array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the PHP variable in your Javascript script so you don't want to convert javascript value to PHP but the opposite : convert php value to javascript like :

```
var formsubmission = <?php echo base_url() ?> + 'index.php/AJAX/get_item';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer a javascript variable to a php variable, there are 2 ways of doing the same.

### Here's How

You can run an ajax request and then shoot an ajax request to your server and save the data into a variable using `$_SESSION` and then get the data back onto `'a php backed page'` using the same session variable.

P.S. Make sure you wrap everything inside an ***`if`*** block because if the ajax request fails due to any reason,then you won't be very glad to have an unassigned php variable being used somewhere.